# Чому часто не вживають літеру "ґ" при нумерації?

Tags: абетка, документація

Часто можна помітити, наприклад, у тестах, що варіанти відповідей нумеруються літерами. Але чомусь літеру `ґ` інколи опускають. Ось [тут](https://erudyt.net/pidgotovka-do-zno/matematyka/zno-2017-vidpovidi-zno-2017-matematyka.html) яскравий приклад. Чому так? Бояться, щоб не переплутали зі схожою літерою `г`?

Comment: Це запитання здається primarily opinion-based. Тому що відповіді сильно залежать від того, хто цю літеру не вживає: від «не знаю про її існування» до «у моєму шрифті `г` та `ґ` мало відрізняються» або причин, подібних до тих, чому [у літаках](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_seat_map#Seat_designation) місця `I` нема, а місце `J` — є. А стосовно ЗНО, навряд чи є регулятивні документи, які б регламентували перелік літер для відповідей.

Comment: У [правописі](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm) «ґ» як окремий пункт у переліках уживають.

Comment: `у літаках місця I нема, а місце J — є` я цього не знав. Цікаво, дякую.

Comment: @Glorfindel, thanks for [the edit proposal](/review/suggested-edits/2656), but this is really not about [numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_(linguistics)) (at least, not about [числівники](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Числівник) as we understand that word).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Існує принаймні один держстандарт *"ДСТУ 3008-95. Документація. Звіти у сфері науки і техніки. Структура і правила оформлення"*, який регламентує (на с. 24) саме таке вживання:

> [7.16.4](http://www.dnu.dp.ua/docs/ndc/standarts/DSTU_3008-95.pdf#page=30) Додатки слід позначати послідовно великими літерами української абетки, за винятком літер Ґ, Є, З, І, Ї, Й, О, Ч, Ь, наприклад, додаток А, додаток Б і т.д.1
>
> Один додаток позначається як додаток А.

Новіша версія того самого стандарту — *["ДСТУ 3008:2015. Інформація та документація. Звіти у сфері науки і техніки. Структура та правила оформлення"](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%A1%D0%A2%D0%A3_3008:2015)* — каже (на с. 17) те саме:

> [7.15.1](http://www.knmu.kharkov.ua/attachments/3659_3008-2015.PDF#page=22) Додатки позначають послідовно великими літерами української абетки, крім літер Ґ, Є, З, І, Ї, Й, О, Ч, Ь, наприклад, ДОДАТОК А, ДОДАТОК Б.
>
> Дозволено позначати додатки літерами латинської абетки, крім літер І та О.
>
> У разі повного використання літер української і/або латинської абеток дозволено позначати додатки арабськими цифрами.
>
> Один додаток позначають як ДОДАТОК А.

Comment: Хотів написати «ласкаво просимо», але помітив, що ви на сайті вже цілий рік. Тоді — вітаю з першим дописом! :)

Comment: Але варіанти відповідей у тестах - це ж не додатки. Тому мали б використовувати літеру Ґ.

Comment: @user2513149 ні, не мали, бо логіка та сама, - ці букви не зручні для нумерації, бо їх можна сплутати з іншими.

Answer (score 4):

На додаток до [відповіді](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/2916/945) про нумерацію *додатків*, існує ще «ДСТУ 1.5:2015 Національна стандартизація. Правила розроблення, викладання та оформлення національних нормативних документів.», введений в дію [наказом ДП «УкрНДНЦ» №217 від 31.12.2015](http://uas.org.ua/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/N217_2015-12-30.pdf), який описує саме нумерацію *переліків* (списків) у національних стандартах:

> 6.2 Переліки
>
> 6.2.1 У пунктах або підпунктах за потреби можна подавати переліки.
>
> Заголовок переліку завершують знаком «:» (двокрапка). Текст кожного пункту переліку почина­ють з малої літери, а завершують знаком «;» (крапка з комою), крім останнього, який завершують знаком «.» (крапка).
>
> 6.2.2 За наявності в тексті переліку одного рівня підпорядкованості кожну його позицію познача­ють малими літерами української абетки, за винятком ґ, є, з, і, ї, й, о, ч, щ, ь, чи арабськими цифрами, або знаками «—» (тире).
>
> 6.2.3 За наявності в тексті переліку двох рівнів підпорядкованості найвищим рівнем є перелік, який позначають малими літерами української абетки, за винятком ґ, є, з, і, ї, й, о, ч, щ, ь, найнижчий позначають арабськими цифрами або знаками «—» (тире).
>
> 6.2.4 За наявності в тексті переліків різних рівнів підпорядкованості найвищим рівнем є перелік, який позначають малими літерами української абетки, за винятком ґ, є, з, і, ї, й, о, ч, щ, ь, середній рівень позначають арабськими цифрами, найнижчий — знаком «—» (тире).
>
> Після цифри або літери, якою позначено певну позицію переліку, ставлять знак «)» (кругла дужка).